# R: csv data ends in one column no matter what reading function I use

Tags: r, excel, csv, read.csv

I didn't expect to ask my first question here about data reading, but here it comes.
I've got "ugly" data files from brain-imaging machine which are in csv format (basically a raw data + a header/description in few rows on top).

I'd like to use R for some simple subsetting. First of all, when I open the data in Excel, it looks like a mess(all in one column), but when I use a reading function in Excel (data, read from csv) it looks normal(and excel tells me it uses comma as a delimiter).

I've tried to use multiple reading functions(even trying different delimiter options) in R, but the thing always ends up in one long ugly column. 
I can bypass it by saving the data in Excel (after first deading them in), but it changes the delimiter and makes it impossible for me to feed the data afterwards to some other custom analysis software.

Thus, I need the data to stay in the same format (and only cut some parts of the raw data) and move on.

Thanks.

Edit: I am adding a link to file download. It is only a few entries of test measurement on my head (there were ~16000 entries before, but I erased most of them to keep it short & private). [You can download the csv here](http://ge.tt/4NuQxLn2)

Edit2: Solved. I realized it might be caused by the way how the functions handle the native header, which was the case. It can be avoided by assigning the header (column) names in the script with col.names. Stupid mistake, still lot to learn :).

Edit - the data looks as follows. Rows 1-39 are the header, and the data starts after row 40 which only has the string 'Data'.

```
Header
File Version,1.21
Patient Information


Comment,,,
Birth Date,0000/00/00
Age,  0y
Sex,Male
Analyze Information
AnalyzeMode,Continuous
Pre Time[s],9.0
Post Time[s],7.0
Recovery Time[s],12.0
Base Time[s],5
Fitting Degree,1
HPF[Hz],No Filter
LPF[Hz],No Filter
Moving Average[s],0.1
Measure Information

Probe Type,adult
Mode,3x3
Wave[nm],695,830
Wave Length,CH1(700.0),CH1(830.8),CH2(698.3),CH2(828.4),CH3(700.0),CH3(830.8),CH4(698.9),CH4(827.8),CH5(698.3),CH5(828.4),CH6(698.9),CH6(827.8),CH7(698.9),CH7(827.8),CH8(699.2),CH8(830.0),CH9(698.9),CH9(827.8),CH10(703.7),CH10(828.2),CH11(699.2),CH11(830.0),CH12(703.7),CH12(828.2),CH13(700.2),CH13(831.2),CH14(701.4),CH14(828.2),CH15(700.2),CH15(831.2),CH16(699.7),CH16(830.7),CH17(701.4),CH17(828.2),CH18(699.7),CH18(830.7),CH19(699.7),CH19(830.7),CH20(698.1),CH20(831.0),CH21(699.7),CH21(830.7),CH22(698.3),CH22(830.6),CH23(698.1),CH23(831.0),CH24(698.3),CH24(830.6)
Analog Gain,59.60784300,59.60784300,59.60784300,59.60784300,600.00000000,600.00000000,59.60784300,59.60784300,242.35294100,242.35294100,600.00000000,600.00000000,242.35294100,242.35294100,600.00000000,600.00000000,235.29411800,235.29411800,242.35294100,242.35294100,235.29411800,235.29411800,235.29411800,235.29411800,31.29411800,31.29411800,31.29411800,31.29411800,284.70588200,284.70588200,31.29411800,31.29411800,200.00000000,200.00000000,284.70588200,284.70588200,200.00000000,200.00000000,284.70588200,284.70588200,75.29411800,75.29411800,200.00000000,200.00000000,75.29411800,75.29411800,75.29411800,75.29411800
Digital Gain,21.76000000,5.61000000,28.46000000,5.76000000,15.21000000,4.46000000,100.00000000,32.86000000,25.72000000,4.09000000,19.43000000,4.42000000,17.86000000,3.81000000,32.66000000,10.99000000,100.00000000,21.47000000,25.16000000,5.03000000,14.26000000,3.62000000,13.59000000,3.06000000,12.91000000,3.42000000,32.35000000,6.98000000,9.66000000,2.11000000,100.00000000,44.11000000,12.41000000,4.17000000,49.73000000,7.74000000,12.48000000,2.81000000,36.93000000,6.75000000,100.00000000,100.00000000,65.63000000,17.46000000,100.00000000,100.00000000,100.00000000,100.00000000
Sampling Period[s],0.1
StimType,EVENT
Stim Time[s]
F1,15,F2,15,F3,15,F4,15,F5,15,F6,15,F7,15,F8,15,F9,15,M,15
Repeat Count,3
Exception Ch,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0






Data
Probe1(Total),CH1,CH2,CH3,CH4,CH5,CH6,CH7,CH8,CH9,CH10,CH11,CH12,CH13,CH14,CH15,CH16,CH17,CH18,CH19,CH20,CH21,CH22,CH23,CH24,Mark,Time,BodyMovement,RemovalMark,PreScan
1,0.01750125,-0.00731065,-0.0229914,-0.01572692,0.04387726,-0.05805205,0.01678475,0.12706034,0.15895581,0.11640126,0.07686448,0.05669941,0.02798176,0.00731046,0.04893643,-0.03621271,0.04504761,0.02515063,0.02962047,0.03181091,-5.10545969,-0.05849782,-2.40030622,42.36789703,0,13:31:07.95,0,0,0
2,-0.01928233,-0.00760579,-0.04548376,0.14481309,-0.02861471,-0.0563355,-0.0301471,-0.07790314,0.0972455,0.08708155,0.02634541,0.03705737,0.00716472,-0.01115488,0.02829455,0.09065069,0.01211305,0.02277327,0.02067163,0.04387939,2.23265266,-0.0207526,-3.71421456,36.16513062,0,13:31:08.06,0,0,0
3,-0.03335796,-0.02295596,-0.07686513,0.01852697,-0.07737321,-0.13283072,-0.10482638,-0.06564587,-0.03146207,0.01997223,-0.02385158,-0.01002161,-0.026086,-0.03784704,-0.02308246,-0.08081956,-0.00761192,0.01914825,-0.00956007,0.00668299,2.47277832,-0.10391754,3.8903904,6.78369522,0,13:31:08.15,0,0,0
```

Comment: Can you provide the first few lines of your data? Assuming it's raw and you can open it in a text editor. And what read function in R did you try?

Comment: You may need to skip the header information before attempting to read the data in.  See the `skip=` option in the read.csv function.  Difficult to help without see an example.

Comment: Hi Rutger & Dave. I've tried read.csv& table, and fread. The header is quite non-standard and I would prefer to leave it that way. I generally only want to delete some entries using R at atm, and use other software to browse the remaining data. I've added a data sample to the original post. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you could do to only edit the 'Data' part of your data.

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
fileName <- 'test_probes.csv'
inString <- readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size)

header <- str_split(inString, 'Data')[[1]][1]
d <- fread(str_split(inString, 'Data')[[1]][2])

## do stuff to d here

# write output to out.csv
write(header, file = 'out.csv')
write('Data', file = 'out.csv', append=T)
write.table(d, file='out.csv', append=T, quote=F, row.names=F, sep=',', col.names=T)
```

Comment: Hi Otto, thank you for your help. I generally love fread for reading big files, but it doesn't work for me not. I've added the data sample to the post.

Comment: Thank you, for your interest and help. That might be useful. Btw since the machine cannot accept more than different 9 triggers (event markers in column 26), I have been forced to code some of my event markers as a succession of several triggers. These are the markers for different experiment blocks. Now I need to go through the column 26 and find places where the entries match a vector (let's say 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1). If I used a simple loop I'd be matching only individual entries, which is not what I need. Any idea which function could do the job? Thanks.